# Numpy item faster than operator[]

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a following code in python that at least for me produces strange results:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.random.rand(3,2)

print timeit.timeit('a[2,1] + 1', 'from __main__ import a', number=1000000)
print timeit.timeit('a.item((2,1)) + 1', 'from __main__ import a', number=1000000)
```

This gives the result:

```
0.533630132675
0.103801012039
```

It seems ok if I only try to access numpy element but when increasing this element the timings get strange... Why is there such a difference in timings?

Comment: Is a[2,1] a shortcut for a.item((2,1)) ? Also, did you try your code more than once?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case, they don't return quite the same thing.  `a[2,1]` returns a `numpy.float64`, while `a.item((2,1))` returns a native python float.

### Native vs `numpy` *scalars* (`float`, `int`, etc)

A `numpy.float64` scalar isn't quite identical to a native python `float` (they behave identically, however).  Simple operations on a single element will be faster with a native python float, as there's less indirection.  Have a look at the [docstring for `ndarray.item`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) for a bit more detail.

As an example of the difference in speed, consider the following:

```
In [1]: x = 1.2

In [2]: y = np.float64(1.2)

In [3]: %timeit x + 1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 58.9 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit y + 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 241 ns per loop
```

---

Initially, I incorrectly stated that a second factor was that `a.item(...)` was slightly faster than `a[...]`.  That actually isn't true. The time it takes for `a.item` to convert the numpy scalar into a native python scalar overwhelms the time it takes for the additional logic in `a[...]`/`a.__getitem__(...)`.

---

### Don't generalize this result to more than one item

However, you should be careful about trying to generalize what happens with numpy scalars to how numpy arrays operate as a whole.  If you're doing a lot of single-item indexing in numpy, it's generally an anti-pattern.

For example, compare:

```
In [5]: a = np.random.rand(1000)

In [6]: %timeit a + 1
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 us per loop
```

No matter what we do, we won't be able to match the speed (or much lower memory usage) of the vectorized version (`a + 1`) above:

```
In [7]: %timeit [x + 1 for x in a]
1000 loops, best of 3: 257 us per loop

In [8]: %timeit [a.item(i) + 1 for i in range(len(a))]
1000 loops, best of 3: 208 us per loop
```

Some of this is because iterating through `ndarray`s is slower than iterating through a list. For a completely fair comparison, let's convert everything over to a list of native python floats:

```
In [9]: b = a.tolist()

In [10]: type(b[0])
Out[10]: float

In [11]: %timeit [x + 1 for x in b]
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.4 us per loop
```

Clearly, using vectorized operations (the first case) is much faster when you're operating on larger arrays.  It's also far more memory efficient, as `list`s require storing pointers to each item, while `ndarray`s are contiguous in memory.